# Flex FileReference doesn't work with NTLM authentication

Tags: apache-flex, file-upload, ntlm, filereference

We use the FileReference component to upload file in Flex. But if the application is deployed within an environment having NTLM authentication (Windows Integrated Authentication), the upload capability will not work, and each time a message box will be popup asking the user to input credentials.

I've queried some resource from internet and it seems this is a bug of FileReference component.

Is there any solution for this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, it isn't possible with FileReference

Also, I think it's important to distinguish that this isn't a bug it's based on known conditions within the client OS and browser - this isn't something that Adobe could fix if they wanted to.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251404

Sorry for the bad news.   :\